# Please reactivate chat room The Auditorium

Tags: support, chat

The Auditorium was created to allow for feedback on user's compositions and performances but closed due to inactivity. A new question has been posted on the main site which is perfect for that chat room, and the OP seems receptive.

[Space to upload and critique home recordings](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/120820/70803)

Comment: Yeah I didn’t know this existed. I have several things that I’d love for people to hear and critique.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Now that it's reactivated, I hope you'll post. It was disappointing that it didn't succeed the first time around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Auditorium is unfrozen. Here is the link for that: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium